# Loading remote data into input text with select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Im trying to loading remote data with select2 but it is not working.

My input text looks like this:

```
<label for="myInput"><input type="text" id="myInput"></label>
```

My select2 initialization:

```
$('#myInput').select2({
     ajax: {
        url: /myUrl
        dataType: 'json'
     }
});
```

My json looks like this:

```
{ "results": [{"id":"1","text":"Test 1"},{"id":"2","text":"Test 2"}]}
```

And im loading select full

```
<script src="/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
```

Hope you can help
Thanks in advance

Comment: For more information, I test it with a select box and its work with the same initialization and json

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the syntax errors with not delimiting your strings, the objects which contain the needed `id` and `text` properties are in the child `results` property. Because of this you need to set the `processResults` function to adapt the data. Try this:

```
$('#myInput').select2({
     ajax: {
        url: '/myUrl',
        processResults: function (data) {
            return { results: data.results };
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: I think results json is ok because i try the same json results with a select box and its work but not with the input text. And i try your solution and still not working, thanks for ur reply